# serverSideTranslations not working with dynamic routes

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next

I did some research on the internet, with the documentation and other answers I could not make it work, so now I am clueless. I have a dynamic route and translate the index.
This does not work when built.
The path is /user/[id]/index.js

```
export const getStaticPaths = ({ locale }) => {
return {
  paths: [
    // if no `locale` is provided only the defaultLocale will be generated
    { params: { slug: ["shop", "account", "navbar", "footer"], id: `1` }, locale: "en" },
    { params: { slug: ["shop", "account", "navbar", "footer"], id: `1` }, locale: "hu" },
    { params: { slug: ["shop", "account", "navbar", "footer"], id: `1` }, locale: "de" },
    { params: { slug: ["shop", "account", "navbar", "footer"], id: `1` }, locale: "lt" },
    { params: { slug: ["shop", "account", "navbar", "footer"], id: `1` }, locale: "cz" },
    { params: { slug: ["shop", "account", "navbar", "footer"], id: `1` }, locale: "pl" },
    { params: { slug: ["shop", "account", "navbar", "footer"], id: `1` }, locale: "ru" },
  ],
  fallback: true,
}
}



export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {

return {
  props: {
    ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["shop", "account", "navbar", "footer"])),
    // Will be passed to the page component as props
  },
};
}

//config
  i18n: {
     // providing the locales supported by your application
    locales: ["en", "ru", "hu", "cz", "pl", "de", "lt"],
    //  default locale used when the non-locale paths are visited
    defaultLocale: "en",
    localePath: "./lang"
  },
```

Comment: Isn't it [locales](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#accessing-the-locale-information) for get static paths? What error are you getting in the build or how doesn't it work?

Comment: I don't get any errors. It just does not translate in build. On my localhost it works, but when built it won't translate anymore.

Comment: Are locales set up in /public/locales/en ('en' as an example) ?

Comment: I find your question very confusing. What are you doing, why and most important of all, what is the question.

Comment: @OdedBenDov my locales are in a lang folder in the root.

Answer (score 0):

From next-i18next [documentation](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next):

> By default, next-i18next expects your translations to be organised as
> such:
>
> ```
> └── locales
>     ├── en
>     |   └── common.json
>     └── de
>         └── common.json
> ```

So if you switched to a `lang` folder make sure to:

> If you want to structure your translations/namespaces in a custom way,
> you will need to pass modified localePath and localeStructure values
> into the initialisation config.

Also, double checking you have `next-i18next.config.js` configured simularly to:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'fr',
    locales: ['fr'],
  },
};
```

Comment: Hey! I edited the question with the config. I have the localePath.

Comment: Did you try with the default path? Just to be sure that's not the issue...

Comment: Oh! You prob want ./public/lang not ./lang (the default is './public/locales' and you still want ./public for the build to work probably)

Comment: So should I move the lang folder from root to public?

Comment: I believe so, that's how I have it set up and working

Comment: With not dynamic routes it works in the root, but I will try.